# How to build std::vector<std::string> from std::initializer_list<char const*>

Tags: c++

What is the correct way to build an `std::vector<std::string>` from an `std::initializer_list<char const*>`? I can iterate through the initializer list and manually build up the vector as such:

```
std::initializer_list<char const*> values;
std::vector<std::string> vec;
for(auto v : values) {
    vec.push_back(v);
}
```

Seems quite verbose. Suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`std::vector` has a constructor that accepts an iterator range as input, as long as the dereferenced values are convertible to the vector's `value_type`:

```cpp
std::vector<std::string> vec(values.begin(), values.end());
```

Comment: @MooingDuck I edited your proof to put a delimiter between the `vector` elements to make it clearer that the constructor did actually work correctly: http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/914f0fa0c4f56ea4